# Neep Help about SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm doing some example of SQL statement.
Let's say that I have these tables:

**Member**

```
MemberID | LastName | FirstName | Birthday | CampusAddress | CampusPhone
```

**FoodItem**

```
FoodItemID | FoodItemName | FoodItemType
```

**_Order**

```
OrderID | MemberID | FoodItemType
```

**OrderLine**

```
OrderID | FoodItemID | Quantity | Price
```

My goal is to list all members (memberID, lastname) who ordered both beef (FoodItemID = "101") and chicken (FoodItemID = "102") on the same order..

I have written two statement :

```
SELECT m.memberid, 
       m.lastname 
FROM   member AS m, 
       _order AS o, 
       orderline AS ol 
WHERE  m.memberid = o.memberid 
       AND o.orderid = ol.orderid 
       AND ol.fooditemid = '101' 
       AND ol.fooditemid IN (SELECT ol.fooditemid 
                             FROM   member AS m, 
                                    _order AS o, 
                                    orderline AS ol 
                             WHERE  m.memberid = o.memberid 
                                    AND o.orderid = ol.orderid 
                                    AND ol.fooditemid = '102')
```

And

```
SELECT m.memberid, 
       m.lastname 
FROM   member AS m, 
       _order AS o, 
       orderline AS ol 
WHERE  m.memberid = o.memberid 
       AND o.orderid = ol.orderid 
       AND ( ol.fooditemid = '101' 
              OR ol.fooditemid = '102' )
```

Which one is right?

Comment: Which one is right depends on what do you want to get. Which you haven't said.

Comment: Have you tried either of your queries?

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @Gnudiff OP did say what they needed.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Edit your question and add some sample table data and the expected result - as formated text, not images. (Then run the queries and see if any of them produces what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say none is right because you are doing implicit joins, which is obsolete in SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.MemberID
                FROM Order o
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM OrderItem o1 
                               WHERE o.orderid = o1.orderid AND       
                                     o1.fooditemid='101') 
                AND
                      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM OrderItem o2 
                               WHERE o.orderid = o2.orderid AND       
                                     o2.fooditemid='102')
```

This should work, but not sure, if it is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

None of your queries answers your requisites. This one should work:

```
select distinct Member.LastName,
                Member.FirstName,
                o1.FoodItemID,
                o2.FoodItemID
    from _order
    inner join _order as o1
        on _order.OrderID = o1.OrderID
    inner join _order o2
        on _order.OrderID = o2.OrderID
    inner join Member
        on _order.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    where o1.FoodItemID = '101'
        and o2.FoodItemID = '102'
```

Here you will get only the orders that have both your food Items Id and they are in the projection view so that you can filter them using the where clause. I don't know if you are dynamically creating your query or not.